# cannot break if condition in objective c

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, for-loop, break

I have a for loop and if conditions as follows,

```
for (snapshot in snapshot.children)
        {
            if([entirePlBtnChecked  isEqual: @"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"leaseType"] intValue] == 2){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                }
            }
            if([hdbApartmntChecked isEqual: @"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"housingType"] intValue] == 0){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                }
            }
            if([condominiumBtnChecked isEqual:@"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"housingType"] intValue] == 1){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                }
            }
            if([landedHouseBtnChecked isEqual:@"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"housingType"] intValue] == 2){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                }
            }
            if([commonRoomBtnChecked isEqual:@"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"leaseType"] intValue] == 0){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                }
            }
            if([masterRoomBtnChecked isEqual:@"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"leaseType"] intValue] == 1){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                }
            }
            if([entirePlaceChecked isEqual:@"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"leaseType"] intValue] == 2){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                }
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[self.allSnapshot count]);
        NSLog(@"%@",self.allSnapshot);
```

when I print the array same object is repeating twice in the array. I want to break the if condition if snapshot value equals the mentioned value in the second if condition inside first if condition. As for an example if [snapshot.value[@"leaseType"] intValue] == 2 is true then this should move to next snapshot, not to next if condition. But when I do in the above way it is checking the next if condition block even if the first if condition block is true. So I get same object repeatedly. I tried the below,

```
for (snapshot in snapshot.children)
        {
            if([entirePlBtnChecked  isEqual: @"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"leaseType"] intValue] == 2){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if([hdbApartmntChecked isEqual: @"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"housingType"] intValue] == 0){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if([condominiumBtnChecked isEqual:@"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"housingType"] intValue] == 1){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if([landedHouseBtnChecked isEqual:@"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"housingType"] intValue] == 2){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if([commonRoomBtnChecked isEqual:@"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"leaseType"] intValue] == 0){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if([masterRoomBtnChecked isEqual:@"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"leaseType"] intValue] == 1){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if([entirePlaceChecked isEqual:@"Yes"]){
                if([snapshot.value[@"leaseType"] intValue] == 2){
                    [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

This break from the first condition and not moving to the second if condition even the first one fails. I get array count as 1 where I should be getting 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `break` for `if`. It is only for loops.

However, in your situation you can use `continue` to enforce the next loop run.

Comment: @S.Sallay just change `break;` to `continue;`